# save UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I've searched for a while but I cannot find the answer to my problem. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITextField`.

I use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to create a table with cells. In the `UIView` that takes the user to the `UITableViewController` the user specifies how many rows they wish to have. When the user goes back and forth the `UITextField` text seems to be lost and does not appear in the `UITableView`

Basically, I cannot get the text that the user inputs to save. Here is my code:

CustomeCell.m

```
@implementation customCell
@synthesize aTextField;

-(void)layoutSubviews{
  aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 65, self.contentView.bounds.size.height-6)];
[aTextField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[aTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[aTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[aTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
aTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
aTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

[self.aTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(aTextFieldEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[aTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
[aTextField setPlaceholder:@"begin"];
[self.contentView addSubview:aTextField];
}

-(void)aTextFieldEditing:(UITextField*)textField{
aTextField.text = textField.text;
}
@end
```

from TableViewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[customCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
return cell;
}
```

Any recommendations? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to populate the cell's text field with the current value for the row.

Comment: Thanks. My question may be more related to fast enumeration.

Comment: No, your question has nothing to do with enumeration. You need to be saving text field values in some sort of data model and you need to use that data model to set the text field's text value in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your guidance. I'm currently trying to get the index path of the cell when the textfield is edited. I have sections in my tableview and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` all i can get is each cell outputting that it is section 0 and row 0 no matter how many sections and rows.

Comment: You need to update your question with the relevant code and describe this issue.